# How can I use methods from a different class objective c

Tags: objective-c, methods

What I want to do is pretty simple but I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I have button that upon clicked, will go to another page. The method that loads a different page is in different class and upon initializing it where I want to use it, I can't see none of the methods belonging to the class.

Here is what I have

```
//HomeViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PhotoView.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "Reachability.h"
#import "BottomTableViewController.h"

@protocol HomeViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

    @optional
    - (void)moveToShowBottomTableView;
    - (void)moveToHideBottomTableView;
    - (void)sendDescriptionToBottomTableView;

@end

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate, BottomTableViewControllerDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *gridView;

    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D userCoordinate;
    CLLocation *initialCoordinate;

    Reachability *internetReachable;
    Reachability *hostReachable;

}

@property (assign, nonatomic) int fromMapView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *clusteredPhotoIDs;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *schoolTitle;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *showDetailsButton;
@property (assign, nonatomic) id<HomeViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bottomTableViewTitle;
- (IBAction)refreshButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)next:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)prev:(id)sender;

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *subviewDescription;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *subviewCopyright;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *subviewAddress;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *photoIDNumber;

@end
```

BottomPanelViewController.m

```
 #import "HomeViewController.h"
-(IBAction)nextPage:(id)sender{
    HomeViewController *homeScreen = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
   // [homeScreen loadPage];//THIS DOESN'T WORK
}
```

HomeViewController.m

```
- (void)loadPage:(NSInteger)page {
    // Do stuff
}
```

I get this error in the part marked as "Doesn't work": 
no visible @interface for HomeViewController declares the selector loadPage

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Compiler error? Run time error? Is `loadPage` actually called but doesn't do what you want? Please update your question with relevant details.

Comment: no visible @interface for HomeViewController declares the selector loadPage

Comment: are you actually presenting/pushing the new view controller (`homeScreen`)? If not, that is most likely your problem.

Comment: What does HomeViewController.h look like?

Answer (score 2):

It seams that your method receive an integer and you are not sending anything `[homeScreen loadPage: (NSInteger) ];`

```
- (void)loadPage:(NSInteger)page {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah. You need to add the method declaration to the .h file. add the line `- (void)loadPage:(NSInteger)page;` in your `@interface` section of the `HomeViewController.h` file. That will make the method available for use outside its class.

Edit: Also, I stand by what I said before, you also need to present the new view controller somehow...

Another Edit: You also need to make sure that the method names and parameter lists are equivalent.

Comment: But the OP isn't trying to call `loadPage:`. They are trying to call a method named `loadPage` (note the lack of a parameter).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys, What I meant to say was that I can't see any of the methods from HomeViewController. So the part that is commented out, // [homeScreen loadPage];//THIS DOESN'T WORK  wouldn't work as it is yes, but my point was that I can't see the loadPage method at all.

Comment: If you cant see the methods that are inside the class from outside the class, just add the method definition to the .h file as I had suggested.